# How would I move these wheels closer together? They're one object, should I split them into 2?

Tags: modeling, animation, objects, transforms

[image]

I'm making wheels for a character design and I'm not sure how to move these wheels inwards closer together as one object. Should I just split them to different objects? I plan on making animations too so is it good to work with a lot of separate objects for that?

Comment: For the moment, if your wheels are one object, you could use a Mirror modifier instead of 2 different meshes, so if you move the wheel from its origin it will also move its mirrored copy

Comment: @moonboots is correct, for symmetrical objects it's best to delete one side in _Edit Mode_ and use the _Mirror Modifier_. It makes adjusting distance from the center point, rescaling or any mesh editing easier since you don't have to do it twice. If you're going to make animations with those wheels, the answer if you should keep them as one object or split them into separate ones depends on the kind of animation you want to do with them. For example, to simply rotate them together you can keep the mirrored object - to move them somehow different from each other they have to be separate.